# In the following figure prove that: $AB+AC>PB+PC$

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the following figure prove that: $AB+AC>PB+PC.$

[image: Problem picture]
It seems that the triangle inequality is useless unless we add something to picture...

Comment: Hint (on the untold assumption that $A$ and $P$ are on the same side of $BC$): let $Q=AP \cap BC$ then use the triangle inequality a few times.

Comment: @dxiv I did that,but couldn't reach the expected result:  $$QP+BQ>BP , QP+CQ>CP , AB+AP>BP,AC+AP>CP , AB+AC>BC$$

Comment: Are those lengths or vectors?

Comment: Just lengths....

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi Sorry, had the wrong $Q$ in my comment, should have been $Q=BP \cap AC\,$. Check out the classic proof from [Euclid's Book 1 Poposition 21](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI21.html).

Comment: @dxiv Thank you , I found the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $BP\cap AC=\{Q\}$. Hence, by triangle inequality we obtain:
$$AB+AC=AB+AQ+QC>BQ+QC=BP+PQ+QC>BP+PC$$
and we are done!

Comment: Thank you sir,very nice and simple:)

Comment: @Hamid Reza Ebrahimi You are welcome! See please my solution here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360813/ It's very easy solution.  I am ready to explain.